# SQL query optimization for fetching data from a large table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have a table that contains 420 million data. I have written a query to fetch the data from this table between 2 dates.

But this query is taking 24 hours to fetch the data. Can anyone help me with the optimized query for my operation?

Oracle query:

```
select * 
from (
  select q.*, ROWNUM AS rn 
  FROM (
    SELECT * 
    from tableName 
    where timestamp between “21-DEC-2018” AND “28-DEC-2018” 
    order by timestamp
  ) q
) where rn between “startIndex” and “endIndex”;
```

Comment: Your query is for Oracle (evidenced by the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn). But you tagged the question mysql. Are you using MySQL? If not, please don't use tags for products that are irrelevant to the question. You want to use tags to gain the attention of people who are best able to answer your question.

Comment: Please don't use words like *crore* that are not globally used or understood. People might totally misunderstand your question.

Comment: Also, the most obvious question is, is `timestamp` indexed, and how many records are there in the range you've given.

Comment: @JamesZ yes timestamp is indexed, and there are close to 24 lakhs plus records for the dates

Comment: What is the point of your `startIndex` and `endIndex` here?  Pagination makes sense if you are, say, presenting results to a human where you know that the human will look at page 1, might venture to page 2 if they were desparate, but would never, ever reach page 10 of results.  If you're presenting results to a human, you would have killed the query when it ran for, say, a minute.  Not for a day.  Running for a day makes me believe that you're trying to fetch all the data by running this particular query in a loop which will be hideously inefficient

Comment: Same comment for *lakh* as to *crore*. Those are only used in India, so please don't use them here.

Comment: You are trying to do pagination is a gigantic set of data. For instantaneous query results you would be far better off using key set pagination.

Comment: @The Impaler can you provide me some sample code for it

Comment: @vyas There are plenty of pages that explain it and its limitations. I would start with https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset.

Answer (score 0):

How about analytic functions?

```
with temp as
  (select tn.*,
     row_number() Over (order by timestamp) rn
   from tablename tn
  )
select *
from temp
where rn between startindex and endindex;
```

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, but how this makes a difference from sub queries. Analytic Functions also internally uses subqueries for aggregation. Except readbality, what is the pros of using Analytic Function

Comment: Still, if `startindex` is a big number this will be time consuming.

Comment: What is the purpose of storing this data in a file?

Comment: @BobC, which *file*? Are you asking me, or vyas?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off with a full table scan if you're going after millions of rows between two dates like that. You additionally want to ensure you are using parallelism which will help not only with the read but also with the huge sort.

```
Select * 
 from(select q.*, 
             ROWNUM AS rn 
        FROM (SELECT /*+ full(tableName) parallel(8) */* 
                from tableName 
               where timestamp between '21-DEC-2018' AND '28-DEC-2018' 
            order by timestamp) q) 
where rn between :startIndex and :endIndex;
```

I'm assuming your server is multi-core and your DBAs have enabled parallelism. Also have the DBAs check the global memory bound in v$pgastat and ensure it's in the hundreds of MB at least (max is 1GB). If it's too small have them raise pga_aggregate_target to give you more sorting memory.

Do *not* throw multiple threads from your Java client at the database for the same date range just to split up work between startIndex and endIndex. That will overtax your database as every thread would have to do the same sort on the same set of millions of records. That's not the right approach. If this is the purpose of the startIndex/endIndex, then don't divide your work like this at all. Instead, either partition the table and have each thread pull a partition, or at the very least, pick a rather unique column like a PK and use MOD or ORA_HASH to divide up the rows. While every thread would still scan the same rows, at least you won't have all that unnecessary redundant sorting going on between the threads. You would however want to lower the amount of parallelism you are asking for to not do too much across all the threads. Try 4 or even 2, just to ensure you get direct path. Talk to your DBA about what's appropriate for your system.

```
SELECT /*+ full(tableName) parallel(2) */ * 
  FROM tableName
 WHERE timestamp between '21-DEC-2018' AND '28-DEC-2018' 
   AND MOD(pkcol,10) = 0 -- for ten threads. next thread asks for 1, next 2, up to 9
```

If you don't have a good numeric column to choose from, you can do the same with anything else by making them strings then ORA_HASHing:

```
AND MOD(ORA_HASH(somecol),10) = 0 -- etc..
```

Comment: Hi @Paul W, iam bit skeptical about this parallelism in oracle. Yes we are doing parallelism from java backend. Can you provide complete query for better understanding

Comment: Hi @Paul W, no iam not throwing multiple threads with same date range, instead we ate throwing multiple threads based on diffeeent date range, one thread will work on one date range and others will work on different date range

Comment: Okay, then what's the purpose of the startIndex/endIndex scoping?

Comment: start index and end index we are using it for different purposes, we are reading all this date and inserting this data into sone files which will be storing in a drive. So this start index and end index are used to make sure no where we are tampering the data and all these start index and end index we are getting from another table which says how much data to be stored in a single file like max threshold value

Comment: You'd probably be better off pulling everything from Oracle and then in Java splitting them up into your multiple files rather than trying to do that in Oracle. ROWNUM will change if your data changes between pulls. It's not a reliable way to do this. But my initial answer is still applicable: full table scan and parallelism. Just communicate with your DBA about how much you can use.

Comment: @littlefoot, the question about storing in a file was for vyas, given his comment above. "we are reading all this date and inserting this data into sone files which will be storing in a drive"